# Can I run LAMP and MEAN on the same Google Compute Engine instance?

Tags: lamp, google-compute-engine, mean-stack

I'm a web solution developer who has worked in the LAMP environment for about 10 years.  I would like to begin slowly phasing out my LAMP dependency and move to MEAN.  For a variety of reasons, I've chosen Google's Compute Engine as my hosting platform.

Can I run both LAMP and MEAN on a single instance of Compute Engine?

Comment: If you can run LAMP and MEAN together on a single Linux computer, then you can do it on a Linux VM on GCE. Have you tried doing this? If you run into an issue, please post a specific problem report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you should be able to, you'll just have to ensure that the two web servers (apache and node.js built in server) are listening on different ports.  Out of the box they do, so try it and report back if you have specific conflicts or unexpected behavior.